# get a response from nameserver by http request?

Tags: php, httprequest, nameservers

I'm creating a dns-overview after you input a domainname. I get my information by using:

```
    $dnsinfo = (dns_get_record($_POST['txtdomein'], DNS_ANY));
```

After I get the information I want to check if the nameservers and mail servers etc. are responding. So i have to request a response. How do i do that with php?

Greetz

Comment: What does "responding" mean?  Does simply being able to connect correspond to the server responding or do you expect to send a request and get a response you can validate?

Comment: i have an ip of a nameserver. i say to the ip "hey are you there" ip response says "yes i am here. sup". when i don't get a response i know nameserver is not responding/offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question is solved.

i'm now using:

```
`$fp = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)or die('Error: socket_create');

//connect to the socket
socket_connect($fp, $nameserver, 53) or die('Error: socket_connect');

if($fp)
{
    //write the package to socket $fp
    socket_write($fp, $package);
    $output = '';

    //get the response from the socket
        $output = socket_read($fp, 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ)or die('Error: socket_read');
      echo $output."<br />";`
```

Thx for the support sberry:)